# Worklight 6.2. Mobile Test Workbench, not able to install the app in iOS

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

iOS 7.1.1

I'm following the instructions of the module "Testing Worklight mobile applications with the Mobile Test Workbench" for testing iOS applications

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/10_12_Testing_Worklight_mobile_applications_with_the_Mobile_Test_Workbench.pdf

After the step "Preparing the application for testing" I see the app in the available applications tab and in the IBM Rational Test Workbench Mobile Client (Using Safari).

The problem is that the install button is disabled and the record button is enabled but when I click it I get the error "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

In the RTW infocenter there are instructions that explains that you must run some scripts before installing the app, but there is no mention about this in the Worklight training module.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtwhelp/v8r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.test.lt.moeb.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_gsios.html

I have generated the iPad environment and deployed it to Worklight, also I have tried to run the app in the iPad and it runs (I uninstalled it after test).

How do I install the app using the IBM Rational Test Workbench Mobile Client.

I have tried also using the script:

```
./rtwBuildXcode.sh /<path>/TestRTWTestRTWIpad.xcodeproj http://192.168.1.41:7878
```

The app appears as available in the Mobile applications with a warning explaining that I have to manage it, I click the button to manage it and the warning disappear but the state is the same, the install button is disabled and the record button is enabled but when I click it I get the error "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

Comment: Are you using Rational Test Workbench, or the Motile Test Workbench for Worklight? Not the same offering.\

Comment: Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight 8.5

Comment: I have edited the question, when I click the record button I get the error: "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS7.1, the installation of an application from the device is no more possible in MTWW (because ITMS protocol requires now a signed certificate, anyway...)

You have 3 ways to install the instrumented application on your device:

1. At the instrumentation phase, connect first your device on your laptop via an USB calbe and simply add 'device' ate the end of the command line ./rtwBuildXcode.sh. After the link phase, MTWW will install the instrumented application on the found device (note that if you are on Wondows, you should install first iTunes)
2. On the Workbench, open the mobile application view, select your iOS application and click on the button on top of this view (see the tooptip 'install on iOS device...'). Again, you should connect first your device on your laptop with USB cable.
3. MTWW provice also a shell script to only install an iOS application on a device (InstallAppInDevice.sh)

I hope it helps!!

Dominique

Comment: It works with the first option, I couldn't find the second one. One more question, how do I distribute the instrumented app? where is the generated .ipa?

Comment: The simplest way is to reuse the .ma file that is stored in your project. You can import this file in another workbench with the button "add an application to list..." in the application editor. The ma file is a zip that contains the ipa file (instrumented, original, fro simulator end for device)

Comment: Hi dom. I was looking for the .ipa so I could put it in the Application Center for example and all the other iOs devices could install it without connecting them to the RTW machine. I understand the .ma is something I have to import in other workspace and install the application manually to the connected dive. It is not something I could distribute to the iOs Devices.